# Powershell cast string to time only

Tags: powershell, rest, xaml

I have created a Powershell/XAML app, that on button press makes a RESTAPI call, parses the JSON response into fields in the app front end. All fine so far.

These fields will be populated with a string representing a time, so "1800" or "2000" etc.

The user can then change this from 1800 to 1900 for example.

This is all fine, and in the background the app will use 1900 to update a setting to be used in a POST back.

However there are other settings that are offset by 90 mins of the time above. I don't want the user to have update each one, which is why I am trying to programmatically.

But try as I might, I cannot take a string of 1800, add 90 mins to it and make the value 1930 (not 1890).

Comment: You could convert the input to a date and then call `AddMinutes(90)` ?

Comment: Yeah been looking at the following `$myTime = [DateTime]'18:00'; '{0:HHmm}' -f
$myTime.AddMinutes(90)`. However my value is 1800 not 18:00, so may just work around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the input as a `DateTime` object (ignoring the date part) and then use the `AddMinutes` method.

```bash
$input = '1800'
$hour = $input.Substring(0,2)
$minute = $input.Substring(2,2)

$dateInputStr = "0001-01-01,${hour}:${minute}:00"
[datetime]$dateInput = ([datetime]$dateInputStr)
$dateInput = $dateInput.AddMinutes(90)
$dateInput.ToString("HHmm")
```

Comment: Got it working using the below also

`$startTime = '1800' 
$startTime = $startTime.Insert(2,':')
$myTime = [DateTime]$startTime; '{0:HHmm}' -f $myTime.AddMinutes(90)`

Comment: Cheers for your help, will accept your answer.

Comment: @DanBot Your solution is better :D You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Using [`[timespan]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instances is another option:

```bash
$time = '1800' 
([timespan] ($time -replace '(?<=^..)', ':') + '01:30').ToString('hhmm') #->'1930'
```

- `$time -replace '(?<=^..)', ':'` uses the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to insert `:` after the first two characters - see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/OhI1Nu/1) for an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it.
- Due to expressing the results only in terms of hours and minutes, the calculation wraps around at midnight, so that adding `'05:30'`, for instance, would yield `'0030'`
- The RHS operand needn't be cast to `[timespan]` directly, because the data type of the LHS - with its explicit `[timespan]` cast - implicitly converts the RHS to `[timespan]` too, with `'01:30'` representing `1` hour and `30` minutes, i.e. `90` minutes.

  - If you want to define the duration to add in terms of `90` minutes, use the following instead (there are analogous static methods for other units, such as `::FromSeconds()`:

    ```bash
    [timespan]::FromMinutes(90)
    ```
  - Alternatively, you can cast a *number* to `[timespan]`, which is  interpreted as *ticks*, which are 100-nanosecond units; there are `1e9` (10 to the power of 9) nanoseconds in a second, and therefore `1e7` 100-nanosecond units in a second. Thus, multiplying with `1e7` gives you seconds, and multiplying that with `60` minutes.

    ```bash
    # 90 minutes expressed as ticks
    [timespan] 90 * (60 * 1e7)
    ```

Answer (score 0):

When I read this question I wanted to solve it with minimal string manipulation, leaning on time related objects and methods instead. `datetime` was the first object I thought of, but it expects a date (year, month, day). Things actually simplify if we use `timespan`. Its static method, `ParseExact`, can parse the string directly.

```
$offsetTimeSpan = [timespan]::FromMinutes(90)

$timeField = '830'
$timeStr = $timeField.PadLeft(4, '0')
$timeSpan = [timespan]::ParseExact($timeStr, 'hhmm', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$offsetTime = $timeSpan.Add($offsetTimeSpan)

$offsetTime.ToString('hhmm')
```

`$timeField` is used to represent the time you get from the RESTAPI. `PadLeft` is only needed if it's possible for a leading 0 to be missing. `ParseExact` does the heavy lifting of converting the string to a time type. Because `timespan` doesn't have an `AddMinutes` member, we use the `Add` method passing in a `timespan` of 90 minutes, `$offsetTimeSpan`.

You don't mention anything about overflowing past midnight. You can test for overflow using `$offsetTime.Days`, if any special processing is required.